# Can't do a click event on an SVG path element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a script that generates a map with colors on it. I am trying to have an event happen when I click on one of the states - this is using jvectormap.

However, for some reason it doesn't work. I try it on other elements, and the click event works fine. How do I get a click event to work with a path element?

```
$(function() {
    var generateColors = function() {
      var colors = {},
          key; 
      for (key in map.regions) {
          values.green.forEach(function(item, i) {
             colors[item] = "#2eb02e";
          });
          values.red.forEach(function(item, i) {
             colors[item] = "#ba0707";
          });
          values.yellow.forEach(function(item, i) {
             colors[item] = "#d2d207";
          });
       }
      return colors;
     },
     map = new jvm.Map({
             map: 'us_lcc_en',
             container: $('#map'),
             series: {
                   regions: [{
                      attribute: 'fill'
                   }]
               }
            });
    map.series.regions[0].setValues(generateColors());
});
```

AND:

```
$("path").click(function() {
     console.log("blah blah blah");
});
```

Preferably the solution would be using jQuery.

Comment: Can you fiddle the problem?

Comment: It is a little difficult as I have local js resources.

Comment: are you importing the svg from a file or have you written svg markup on your page??

Comment: It is being generated dynamically by jVectorMap. I just tried changing my binding method to .on() and that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: <script>$("path").on("click", "path", (function() {
    console.log("blah blah blah");
    alert("blah");
}));</script>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be because when you import it the svg markup isn't loaded on the page yet so it cannot attach events to the path elements.

What you have to do is attach a load event to the object that when fired will attached your click events once it has been loaded.

You can either do this

```
$(document).on('click','path',function(){
        alert('You clicked me');
        //Do the stuff
});
```

Or

```
<script>
        var a = document.getElementById("somesvg");
        //it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
        a.addEventListener("load",function(){
            var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; //get the inner DOM of some.svg
            var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("delta"); //get the inner element by id
            delta.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){alert('hello world!')},false);    //add behaviour
        },false);
</script>
```

**NOTE -** Note that a limitation of this technique is that it is restricted by the same-origin policy, so some.svg must be hosted on the same domain as the html file, otherwise the inner DOM of the object will be inaccessible.

Comment: Path is the element, not a class

Comment: Changed it to path the element rather than a class named path, and it worked.